# Selected Radio button in Formula Field within flow builder

Tags: formula-field, radio-button, flow-builder

I created a screen in flow builder having a Radio Btn component(type boolean)

[image]

I also create a formula field smoke_lv(type boolean) to capture the selected radio button value.

I am using the following code to get the value assigned to true if "Yes" is selected, but the formula field always has value "false". Any inputs what I may be doing wrong here?

```
if({!smokeRB} = true, true, false )
```

I also tried other variations like `if({!smokeRB} = {!yesSmoke}, true, false )` but I still get the value 'false' in the smoke_lv variable.

Any suggestions please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.
I had forgotten to provide the 'yesSmoke' and 'noSmoke' choice values as true or false.
The correct value is now set.
Thanks